# EditText monitor the cursor position

Tags: java, android, textwatcher, getselection

I want to use the cursor position to do something, so write this code:

```
input =(EditText)findViewById(R.id.Input_EditText); 
input.addTextChangedListener(new TextWatcher() 
{
    public void onTextChanged(CharSequence s, int start, int before, int count) {   
    }
    public void beforeTextChanged(CharSequence s, int start, int count, int after) {    
    }
    public void afterTextChanged(Editable s) 
    {
        int index = input.getSelectionEnd();
        if(index==0)
        {
            //do nothing
        }
        else
        {
            Toast.makeText(MainActivity.this, Integer.toString(index), Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();
        }
    }
});
```

But if you press the newline key, then press the Delete key, then the program will crash

Will the problem is where?

Comment: what is your logcat says?

Comment: Sorry an error in this article I described, and has made changes

Comment: I found an error in which, thank you